# How to fix typeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I want to get data from Json Server, where do i need to edit ?

this the error i get

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
getPosts() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            posts : response.data.posts,
            isLoading: false
        });
    })

    .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading : false}));
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.getPosts();
}

render() {
  const {isLoading , posts} = this.state;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Data JSON</h2>
        <div>
            {!isLoading ? (
                posts.map(post => {
                    const {id, first_name, last_name, email} = post;
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h2>{id}</h2>
                            <h2>{first_name}</h2>
                            <p>{last_name}</p>
                            <p>{email}</p>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

}

export default login;

i expect the data from json server is appear but its not

Comment: Post the full component as well as the response from the server that you are getting. The error you are facing means that you are trying to access the property map from data that is not an **array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props) 
   this.state()={isLoading: true, posts: []}
}
getPosts() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
    .then(response => {
        var posts = [];
        if(response.data.posts.length > 0) {
          posts = response.data.posts
        }
        this.setState({isLoading: false, posts: posts})   
     })

    .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading : false, posts: []}));
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.getPosts();
}

render() {
  const {isLoading , posts} = this.state;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Data JSON</h2>
        <div>
            {!isLoading ? (
                posts.map(post => {
                    const {id, first_name, last_name, email} = post;
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h2>{id}</h2>
                            <h2>{first_name}</h2>
                            <p>{last_name}</p>
                            <p>{email}</p>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: i already did it before . 
class login extends React.Component {
state = {
posts: [],
isLoading: true,
errors: null };
error in <div> . i want to get data table from json
   31 | return (
   32 |<React.Fragment>
   33 |<h2>Data JSON</h2>
> 34 |<div>
   35 | ^
   36 |{!isLoading ? (
   37 |posts.map(post => {
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/fernando.siregar/project/my-app/src/login.js:14
   11 |getPosts(){
   12 |axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
   13 |then(response =>{
> 14 |this.setState({
   15 | ^
   16 |posts : response.data.posts,
   17 |isLoading: false

Answer (score 0):

Set default state for posts as array and add if statement to your render function to check that component should render posts.

```
class YourClassName extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
  }

  getPosts() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            posts : Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : response.data.posts,
            isLoading: false
        });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading : false}));
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  render() {
    <>
      {posts.length > 0 && posts.map(post => <p>{post}</p>)}
    </>
  }
}
```

Comment: i already did it before . 
class login extends React.Component {
state = {
posts: [],
isLoading: true,
errors: null };
error in <div> . i want to get data table from json
   31 | return (
   32 |<React.Fragment>
   33 |<h2>Data JSON</h2>
> 34 |<div>
   35 | ^
   36 |{!isLoading ? (
   37 |posts.map(post => {
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/fernando.siregar/project/my-app/src/login.js:14
   11 |getPosts(){
   12 |axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
   13 |then(response =>{
> 14 |this.setState({
   15 | ^
   16 |posts : response.data.posts,
   17 |isLoading: false

Comment: are you sure that in response are you getting posts in array?

Comment: i want get data from this link http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, and the error is on <div>

class login extends React.Component {
      state = {
      posts: [],
      isLoading: true,
      errors: null
    };

Comment: and if i get from this link "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/posts.json" , it succes and no error but if i get data from another link like jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, output error on div i dont know .

Comment: Those two links has different structure. You want to get `posts` from your response. In http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos you don't have it. ;)

Comment: nah that's what i want to say sir, how if i want to get data from  jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, should i use function check data.length ?

Comment: maybe try something like this: `posts : isArray(response.data) ? response.data : response.data.posts `

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are trying to map `posts` before they even exist.

You need to set `isLoading` to `true` in `componentDidMount`, if you haven't done it in the`constructor`.

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    this.getPosts();
}
```

Your `catch` block has a problem as well.

```
catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading : false}));
```

You set `isLoading` to false, then in the render method, you have this:

```
{!isLoading ? (
      posts.map(post => { 
      //....
```

You are trying to render posts, even when you have an error in the `response`.

Comment: i already did it before . 
class login extends React.Component {
state = {
posts: [],
isLoading: true,
errors: null };
error in <div> . i want to get data table from json
   31 | return (
   32 |<React.Fragment>
   33 |<h2>Data JSON</h2>
> 34 |<div>
   35 | ^
   36 |{!isLoading ? (
   37 |posts.map(post => {
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/fernando.siregar/project/my-app/src/login.js:14
   11 |getPosts(){
   12 |axios.get("http://localhost:8001/employees")
   13 |then(response =>{
> 14 |this.setState({
   15 | ^
   16 |posts : response.data.posts,
   17 |isLoading: false